# How do I merge keywords in Apple Photos?

Tags: photos.app

How do I merge keywords in Apple Photos? I've tired various common methods (e.g. renaming to the same keyword); but none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7241238)

> To merge two keywords "key1" and key2" I would create a smart album with the rule "keyword is key1" or "keyword is key2". Then assign the new merged keyword to the photos in this smart album.
>   And then delete both old keywords in the edit mode of the keyword manager.
>   It is no problem to create a temporary smart album with "File > new smart album" for the search and to delete it when you are done. I keep one smart album that I always use for searching.
>
> If you are using iCloud Photo Library this may result in a very long period of syncing, if you have to change the keyword in many photos.

Comment: Wow. So there’s no way to actually merge keywords?

Comment: @orome nope, that is the only solution

Comment: Incredible (but typical)!